# Type alias with same name as type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, alias

Is this valid in C++?

```
#include <iostream>


class Test {

    struct Inner {
    };

public:
    using Inner = struct Inner;  // Alias with same name as type
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    static_assert(std::is_pod<Test::Inner>::value, "");
    
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation is fine with Clang but not GCC / Visual C++ ("Inner is private..." error message).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC and Visual C++ are correct.

Indeed you can use `using` to in effect change the access of a member, e.g.

```
using Inner_ = Inner;
```

with

```
static_assert(std::is_pod<Test::Inner_>::value, "");
```

in the function.

But in the case where the type alias has the same name as the member, C++ requires that the scope resolution operator looks up the member. So in your case `Test::Inner` refers to the actual member rather than to the `using` and compilation should therefore fail as it's `private`.

---

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup, and in particular

> Qualified lookup within the scope of a namespace N first considers all
>   declarations that are located in N and all declarations that are
>   located in the inline namespace members of N (and, transitively, in
>   their inline namespace members). If there are no declarations in that
>   set then it considers declarations in all namespaces named by
>   using-directives found in N and in all transitive inline namespace
>   members of N

Comment: Not sure if the quote applies. `using x = y;` is not a using-*directive*, but a using-*declaration*, if I understand [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using) correctly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It's a tricky one. I'm pretty sure this is correct (I recall coming across this some time ago at a conference). I'm pretty sure too that the program is not simply ill-formed. Hopefully one of the language experts will wade in. I'll fiddle with the question tags to attract attention.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's not even a using-declaration (e.g., `using std::swap;`); it's an alias-declaration.

Answer (score 1):

[P1787R6: Declarations and where to find them](http://wg21.link/P1787R6), merged into C++23 draft, seems to favor Clang's behavior:

> [[basic.lookup]](http://wg21.link/P1787R6#basic.lookup)
>
> > In certain contexts, only certain kinds of declarations are included. **After any such restriction, any declarations of classes or enumerations are discarded if any other declarations are found**. [Note: A type (but not a *typedef-name* or template) is therefore hidden by any other entity in its scope. — end note] However, if a lookup is *type-only*, only declarations of types and templates whose specializations are types are considered; furthermore, if declarations of a *typedef-name* and of the type to which it refers are found, the declaration of the *typedef-name* is discarded instead of the type declaration.

So the declaration of `struct Inner` is discarded, because the *alias-declaration* is found. (One can put `Inner` into type-only context — `Test::struct Inner` — and it will refer to the `struct Inner` declaration, per the second part of the paragraph).